# The proper way of creating many instance of a class

Tags: python, design-patterns, solid-principles

I am trying to develop a class that tokenizes a sentence with a pre-defined pattern. My class is defined as below:

```py
class Token:

    def __init__(self, text: str, begin: int, end: int, tid: int):
        self.__text = text
        self.__length = len(text)
        self.__begin = begin
        self.__end = end
        self.__tid = tid

    @property
    def text(self) -> str:
        return self.__text

    @property
    def begin(self) -> int:
        return self.__begin

    @property
    def end(self) -> int:
        return self.__end

    @property
    def tid(self) -> int:
        return self.__tid

    def __len__(self):
        return self.__length
```

Since this class is used to process large documents with lots of tokens, Many instances are created. I have defined my own tokenize class as follows:

```py
def tokenizer(sentence):
    list_of_tokens = []
    # tokenizing algorithm
    # creating an instance of Token
    # adding each instance into list_of_tokens
    return list_of_tokens
```

Now my question is whether it is correct to use @classmethod in python(like below) to help this issue or create just another function out of the class that does so?

```py
@classmethod
def tokenenizer(cls, sentence):
    list_of_tokens = []
    # tokenization
    # create instance of Token with cls(*arg)
    # add each token into list_of_tokens
    return list_of_tokens # that holds objects of Token
```

Comment: This is entirely up to your preference. There are not technical reasons to do one over the other as far as I know.

Comment: On the other hand, you should look into generators and `yield`. Since you say you will have a lot of tokens, using a generator instead of building the entire list of tokens will be more efficient on memory usage.